# Can't get code suggestions in graphql files

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I'm trying to learn GraphQL and I wanted to use it in a spring boot project. But I can't get any suggestion, so I don't really know what I'm doing.

I tried to install the GraphQL Language Feature support on VS Code and configure it, but didn't work. Plus, I thought that spring boot graphql dependency could already help me with that. I tried to do something on Eclipse too, but without results. What should I do?